# Does my portable SSD come ready to use?

Tags: ssd

I have a new SanDisk Extreme Portable 1TB SSD and upon plugging it into my Ubuntu 20.04 system, it appears ready to use.

However, it is worth noting that the SSD is for my wife to use on Windows systems.

My question is this: do I need to format it first?

I have looked for instructions around this but can't find anything useful.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using a neutral file-system format that doesn't support permissions,
because Windows and Linux permissions are not compatible.

FAT32 is the best choice, if no file is expected to exceed 4 GB in size.

For larger files, the exFAT format is a good choice.

NTFS is not the best choice here, because file-permissions are not compatible.

If the disk is to be used only on Windows, NTFS is the best fromat,
but any formatting is best done on Windows.
(Check first if perhaps the factory format the disk came with is enough.)

Answer (score 2):

It should be fine out of the box, although make sure you reformat to the right file system if necessary. If it's exclusively going to be used in Windows you can use any Windows FS, but if you're using it between Linux and Windows you'd want to go with something cross-compatible like NTFS.

- Please see harrymc's answer about NTFS file permissions being incompatible between the two operating systems